# Oracle RMAN full backup due to gaps in ARCHIVE LOGs

Tags: backup, oracle, database-restore, oracle9i, rman

I've recently recovered a Data Guard configuration.  Simple setup that syncs from primary to standby using Data Guard.

Because it's been on-line for a sustained period, some logs are missing and I need to do a full export.

From what I understand, a full export using RMAN can be accomplished on a running primary as long as the archive logs are taken in the back up.

Is this correct? are there any caveats I should be aware of?

TIA

Answer (score -1):

You can use the RMAN command: `RECOVER FROM SERVICE`

See details here http://oracledba.blogspot.co.il/2015/10/rolling-forward-aphysical-standby.html

Yossi

Comment: No link only answers please. Expand your answer.